# How to deploy github project of size 876 MB?

Tags: github

I have successfully managed to upload project of size 876 MB on my Github repo by using code `git config --global http.postBuffer 2097152000` but, I'am trying to deploy it on github pages from 5 days, and still no result. So many errors I'am encountering like 'pack out of memory', 'File too large'. I have even used above code, but, no effect. Is there any appropriate solution for this? Any suggestion or changes highly appreciated

Comment: What about Git LFS?

Comment: I have already tried Git LFS but, still finding hard to deploy

Comment: @dan1st What I have done uploaded image files of size 800MB to lfs first and then rest of my code, but, it got stuck unexpectedly while pushing. So I had to delete the repo

Comment: How to remove the files from lfs? As I've deleted the repo and so I need to remove all files from lfs

Comment: See https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage

Comment: You can also re-initialize the repo.

Comment: Ok thanks... One more doubt, well I would reinitialize repo, but, shall I add images to lfs and commit or push all to repo and then add to lfs?

Comment: Because I have fear if I add images to lfs and then commit rest all the code, those images would be added again and increase memory

Comment: You could upload the images somewhere else and link them

Comment: If you want them in the same repo, just create a pages and a resource branch. The images href to the raw/download link of the resource branch. (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/<branch>/<path>)

Comment: Ok you mean upload images on one repo and link from my current repo?

Comment: No, just another branch. Select the pages (master) branch for deploying to gh-pages and create another branch just for resources.

Comment: I don't know how to do but, I will try

Comment: The solution with another repo is possible the same way.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try

Comment: You can create a new branch using the `git branch` command.

Answer (score 1):

Beside checking with [GitHub support](https://support.github.com/), you should try an incremental approach and:

- publish only a small subset of files first, making sure they are rendered properly
- publish the rest by small successive batches and see if there is a breaking point.